# PHP: call a string from another page function?

Tags: php

Can you do that? I just tried but it doesnt seem to work.

I have dbc.php included at top of my page, and in dbc.php at the bottom i created this function:

```
function getUserInfo($id) {
$thaString = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'");
$thaString2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_profile WHERE uID = '$id'");
$showUR = mysql_fetch_array($thaString);
$showURP = mysql_fetch_array($thaString2);
}
```

So it would be easier for me to call them instead of running the queries all the time when i need them in other pages.. 
But when i try to do:

```
getUserInfo($showInfo["bID"]);
echo $showUR["full_name"];
```

I dont get any result, is there a smarter way to do this, if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issue of scope: `$showUR` is set inside `getUserInfo()`, so it's not available to the `echo` outside the function. There are lots of potential modifications you could make, but you may want to assign your values into an array and then return that array:

```
function getUserInfo($id) {
    $user = array();

    $thaString = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'");
    $thaString2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_profile WHERE uID = '$id'");
    $user['showUR'] = mysql_fetch_array($thaString);
    $user['showURP'] = mysql_fetch_array($thaString2);

    return $user;
}

$user = getUserInfo($showInfo["bID"]);
echo $user['showUR']["full_name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your functions have to return something for the values to be used, or `$showUR` and `$showURP` will just get lost once the function exits (ie: the scope will change). Something like:

```
function someFunc($arg) {
    return "Hello, I am {$arg}";
}

$showUR = someFunc('name');
echo $showUR;
```

And please don't call stuff `$thaString`. First because it's a misnomer (`mysql_query()` doesn't return a string, it returns a resource or a boolean), Second because "tha" is *so* lame.

Answer (score 0):

Let your function return the variable.

And then use $showUR = getUserInfo(...)

Answer (score 0):

If you declare them outside the function, and then as globals inside the function you should be able to use them as you are now.